# could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:4.6

Tags: gradle

Im trying to run an app I wrote in a diffrent computer and I get this error:

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.pom
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :
>   Open File

I've Updated anything I could think of but nothing works. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give more contextual information.

Since I lack these information, I can only make a guess: did you specify the new **google()** maven repository in your project build.gradle file?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        google() // this replace https://maven.google.com
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

If you need google() repository in your module(s), you can also add this in your  project build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        google()
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the latest, use this:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }    // here... try adding this line 
}
```